# Structural type refinement and type equality

Tags: scala, reflection, structural-typing

I stumbled upon a puzzling behaviour of `Type.=:=` when applied on type refinments.
Consider:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
type T1 = AnyRef {
  def apply( name: String ): Unit
  def foo: String
}

type Base = { def apply( name: String ): Unit }
type T2 = Base {
  def foo: String
}
```

Given that `Base` is an alias for a type refinement, I would expected that refining it further by adding the member `foo` would 
yield the same type as if I had defined `foo` right in `Base`.

Or in other words, I would expect that `T1` and `T2` denote entirely equivalent types.

For the most part, scalac seems to agree.
By example I can pass an instance of `T2` where an instance of `T1` is expected:

```
def f( x: T1 ){}
f( null: T2 ) // scalac does not complain here
```

And conversely:

```
def g( x: T2 ){}
g( null: T1 ) // scalac is still happy
```

I can also ask for an evidence `T1 =:= T2` and it compiles fine too:

```
implicitly[T1 =:= T2]
```

**However**, using scala reflection I get entirely different results:

```
scala> typeOf[T1] =:= typeOf[T2]
res2: Boolean = false
```

So is this a scala reflection bug (I would guess so) or is there a fundamental reason (technical of otherwise) why `typeOf[T1] =:= typeOf[T2]` would return false?

Comment: `typeOf[T1] <:< typeOf[T2]` and conversely are also true.

Comment: That's a nice observation. At least there is *some* consistency then. The other great thing is that at the very least it provides me with a workaround: I can just test for `(typeOf[T1] <:< typeOf[T2]) && (typeOf[T2] <:< typeOf[T1])`. Obviously this still feels like a hack though

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, it looks to be this bug: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8177

On the plus side... it looks like there's work actively underway to fix it :)

Comment: +1 for pointing me to related bug(s). But I am not sure this is the bug I'm experiencing. SI-8177 is about dependent types and invalid handling of type prefixes. The only way I can think this affects my above code snippet is because my type aliases have different prefixes. This is indeed the case in the REPL, but I tried wrapping all the definitions in the same object (=> same prefix) and I still get the same error. It is possible though that fixing SI-8177 will fix my problem as a side effect. I'll try with 2.11.0-RC1 when it's out, and if fixed I'll validate your answer.

Comment: OK, scala 2.11.0-RC1 has just been released, so I tried against it (seeing as SI-8177 is marked as fixed in scala 2.11.0-RC1). The bug is definitly still there, so as I suspected SI-8177 does not cover my described problem. Maybe it's time to open a ticket.